# How can I add background color and image at a fixed position in a pdf at the same time using iText in java?

Tags: java, itext7

I am new to itext library. I want to add both background colour and image at a fix position at each page in my pdf. I tried to make use the following code given by itext community for my work - https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-all-pages-of-my-pdf

```
public static class ImageEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
        protected Image img;

        public ImageEventHandler(Image img) {
            this.img = img;
        }
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
            PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
            Rectangle area = page.getPageSize();
            PdfCanvas aboveCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(),
                    page.getResources(), pdfDoc)
                    .setStrokeColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
                    .setFillColor(new DeviceRgb(240, 230, 140))
                    .rectangle(area)
                    .fillStroke()
                    .restoreState();
            new Canvas(aboveCanvas, pdfDoc, area)
                    .add(img);
        }
    }
```

With this image is coming on each page with background colour but other contents like paragraph and cells are hidden. Please help me understand how to use this concept?

Comment: For which events do you register your event listener? And have you tried `newContentStreamBefore()` instead of `newContentStreamAfter()`?

Comment: `Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(IMAGE));
img.scaleAbsolute(100, 50);
ImageEventHandler handler = new ImageEventHandler(img);
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, handler); `  
I am using listening on addEventHandler .  Also when I am using newContentStreamBefore() I am getting `Unbalanced save restore state operators` error.

Comment: *"Also when I am using newContentStreamBefore() I am getting Unbalanced save restore state operators error."* - that's no wonder, you do `restoreState()` without having saved it before.

Comment: *`pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, handler);`* - if upon end of page you add content *after*, you paint it *over* anything previously added.

Comment: @mkl Thanks a lot. This resolved my issue.